# how to close the </source> tag to be read by a separate svg file

Tags: javascript, html, xml, svg

hi i wish i would create a svg with video but i can't close the  tag online, to collect the svg and be read from a separate file, it gives the error
XML read error: label mismatch. Expected: .

````
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function scripenvivo(){
      
 //var e=document.getElementById('hola');


//var textnode = document.createTextNode("</source>");        
//e.appendChild(textnode);  
var sor =document.getElementById('soyunsvgconvideo').innerHTML  
alert(sor)
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div Id="soyunsvgconvideo">
    <svg class="img-responsive" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 1470 800 ">

    <foreignObject id="i" requiredExtensions="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml " width="640" x="500" y="300" height="352" >
<g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" preload="auto" class="a64" width="640" height="352"> 
<source  x="300" y="225" src="https://animacionesweb.online/videos/City-3134.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 
 </video>
</g>
 </foreignObject>
 
  </svg>        

    </div>
    
    <input type="button"  onclick=scripenvivo() value ="pulsame"></imput>
    
</body>

</html>```
````

Comment: `<source ...blah blah .... />`

Comment: hello but in an alert how do I make it appear </source>